# Position of label in a subfigure

Tags: labels, subfig

I try to have three images in a subfigure. The first and second next to each other, the third image should be below the first. I read to use the package `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` which puts my third image from the center to the left, that's what I wanted to do. But the label "Label 3" is still centered. Can someone help me how to get the label to the left side under the image?

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfigure[Label 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}}
\hfill
\subfigure[Label 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2.pdf}}
\\[5pt]

\subfigure[Label 3]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth, left]{fig/hist3.pdf}}


\label{Images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use \centering.  The \hfill in the first row overwhelms it, so ALL it does is center the second row.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `tabular` to organize subfloats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[Label 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
&
\subfloat[Label 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\\[5pt]
\subfloat[Label 3]
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Main figure with three subfigures\label{Images}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]